# Steiner Construction of Rational Normal Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-curves, projective-varieties

I learned in this [script](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/287y.pdf) on Geometry of Algebraic Curves by Joe Harris
that a rational normal curve
can be constructed by a nice, old-fashioned construction,
called the Steiner construction (page 79). It works as follows:

Let say we have $\Lambda_1, ..., \Lambda_n \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-2} \subset 
\mathbb{P}^{n} $ codimension two subspaces in
$\mathbb{P}^{n} $. Let for every $i =1,...,n$ be $\{H_t^i \}_{t \in \mathbb{P}^{1}}$
the pencil of hyperplanes containing the plane $\Lambda_i$
with
*additional assumption* that for every $t_0 \in \mathbb{P}^{1}$ the planes
$H_{t_0}^1,...H_{t_0}^n$ are independent, i.e., intersect in a unique  point $p(t_0)$.

Consider the union of
intersections of these hyperplanes:

$$ C:= \bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_t^1 \cap ... \cap H_t^n $$

Claim: $C \subset \mathbb{P}^{n} $ is a rational normal curve.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165349/geometric-characterization-of-rational-normal-curves-alebraic-geom-by-j-harris) I tried to prove it directly by tour de force, ie solving simultaneously the linear system consisting of $n$ linear equations

$$ \lambda L_{1, i} + \mu L_{2, i} = 
a_{i,Z_0} (t)Z_0+ a_{i,Z_1} (t)Z_1 + ...
+ a_{i, Z_d} (t)Z_d $$

associated to vanishing sets of $H_t^i$ where $t=(\lambda: \mu)$ and $L_{j,i}$ linear forms in
$Z_0,..., Z_n$. The final solution was that if we define
the matrix $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_{n+1}(K[\lambda_0, \lambda_1])$ such that
it's $i$-th row equals $(a_{i,Z_0} (t), a_{i,Z_1} (t), ...
a_{i, Z_d} (t) )$ and the $n+1$ row is the zero row, then one can check that the solution
is the last coloumn of the adjugate matrix $R$ to $A$, that's the unique matrix with
$AR=RA= det(A) \cdot I_{n+1} 0$. Ok, but now my

*Question* is if it is also possible to show that $C$ is rational normal curve by a
coordinate free argument using intersection count. Namely it is known that ration normal curves in
$\mathbb{P}^{n} $ are exactly irreducible, smooth curves of degree $n$.

So our job is to verify that $C:= \bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_t^1 \cap ... \cap H_t^n$
is irreducible, smooth of degree $n$.

It is irreducible since the map $\mathbb{P}^{1} \to C, t \mapsto p(t)$ is continuous. How can we
show smoothness and degree $n$? Firstly is it non-degenerated (see also this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4176890/ration-normal-curve-is-non-degenerated)  which dedicated the non-degeneracy of $C$)?

For degree we have to show that for *general* hyperplane $H \subset \mathbb{P}^{n} $ the
intersection $C \cap H$ consists of exactly $n$ points. Could somebody help?