# Non-Degeneracy of Ration Normal Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, algebraic-curves, projective-varieties

We consider the so called 'Steiner construction', which
can be looked up e.g. in [this script](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/287y.pdf) e.g. which gives us an irreducible curve.

The construction works as follows: Let say we have $\Lambda_1, ..., \Lambda_n \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-2} \subset 
\mathbb{P}^{n} $ codimension two subspaces in
$\mathbb{P}^{n} $. Let for every $i =1,...,n$ be $\{H_t^i \}_{t \in \mathbb{P}^{1}}$
the pencil of hyperplanes containing the plane $\Lambda_i$
with
*additional assumption* that for every $t_0 \in \mathbb{P}^{1}$ the planes
$H_{t_0}^1,...H_{t_0}^n$ are independent, i.e., intersect in a unique  point $p(t_0)$.

Consider the union of
intersections of these hyperplanes:

$$ C:= \bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_t^1 \cap ... \cap H_t^n $$

In the linked script is is claimed that this curve
is a rational normal curve, i.e. projectively equivalent
to the curve obtained as image of the Veronese map

$$ v_d: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^n,
[X_0:X_1] \mapsto [X_0^n: X_0^{n-1}X_1:..., X_1^n]$$

In  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170453/steiner-construction-of-rational-normal-curve) I wanted to discuss how to prove that the Steiner construction
above gives indeed a  [rational normal curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_normal_curve)
defined in more 'conventional' sense as Veronese's image.

Here I want to prove a weaker statement inspired by a user's comment
which is unfortunately meanwhile removed.
**Question/Problem**: How to show that this curve
$C= \bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_t^1 \cap ... \cap H_t^n \subset \mathbb{P}^n$
constructed above is *non-degenerated*, that means there is no
hyperplane $\mathbb{P}^{n-1} \cong H \subset \mathbb{P}^n$, which contains $C$? If we clearly already know that $C$ ration normal curve, then it's clear, but let's play only with Steiner's construction as definition of $C$.

The problem is that the spaces
$\Lambda_1, ..., \Lambda_n \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-2} \subset 
\mathbb{P}^{n}$
in the construction seem to be choosen arbitrary and that makes it hard
for me to prove the claim.

A simple case I can solve myself is if the
$\Lambda_1, ..., \Lambda_n  \subset 
\mathbb{P}^{n}$  can be choosen as follows: Let
$p_1,..., p_n \in C$ be points in general position, that is
the linear closure $\overline{p_1,..., p_n}$ is a hyperplane $H$, that is a linear subspace of
codimension one in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Take $\Lambda_i := \overline{p_1,..., \hat{p_i},..., p_n}$ where
$\hat{p_i}$ mean that this point was removed. Then one concludes
that if there exist a hyperplane $H$ which contains $C$ then it
is equals to $\overline{p_1,..., p_n}$. But then by construction it
is easy to see that if we chose $t \in \mathbb{P}^1$ such that
for all $i=1,..., n$ the hyperplane $H^i_t \neq H$, then the
intersetion of $H_t^1 \cap ... \cap H_t^n$ with $H$ is empty, therefore
$H_t^1 \cap ... \cap H_t^n \not \in H$.

But the Steiner construction assumes
$\Lambda_1, ..., \Lambda_n \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-2} \subset 
\mathbb{P}^{n}$ to be pairwise distinct but otherwise arbitrary.
How can I show that non-degeneracy of
$C= \bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_t^1 \cap ... \cap H_t^n \subset \mathbb{P}^n$
in that case?
My idea was to find enough points $p_1,..., p_n$ with
$p_i \in \Lambda_i$ which are in general position and then as above
to show that there is a point $c \in C$ which isn't contained
in $\overline{p_1,..., p_n}$.

Problem: Can I such points always be found? Are results/estimations known how many points of $C$ should a $\Lambda_i$ contain? How can I show that every $\Lambda_i$
contains a point $p_i$ such that $p_1,..., p_n \in C$ are in general position,
i.e. span a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$?

Comment: Note that you indirectly stated in your original question that the curve was non-degenerate: You wrote that $P(\lambda)$ has the form $[A_0(\lambda):...:A_n(\lambda)]$  with the $A_i$s forming a basis. The curve is degenerate iff the $A_i$s satisfy a non-trivial linear relation in which case the curve is contained in the hyperplane defined by the linear relation. Hence if the $A_i$s form a basis the curve is non-degenerate. But it was unclear to me how you obtained that the $A_i$s form a basis.

Comment: In 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165349/geometric-characterization-of-rational-normal-curves-alebraic-geom-by-j-harris
I think that I failed to notice this important detail so my statement there on linear independence
of $A_i(\lambda)$ is at least not clear (or wrong?). You are right, for a curve defined as image of
$\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^d, \lambda \mapsto [A_0(\lambda):...:A_n(\lambda)]$ 
with homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $\lambda_0, \lambda_1$ 
the linear independence of the $A_i(\lambda)$ is indeed equivalent 
to nondegeneracy of the image.

Comment: In
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170453/steiner-construction-of-rational-normal-curve
I sketched at least how one obtains formally a solution: What is definitelly true that
if every linear equation $\lambda_0 L_{1,i} + \lambda_1 L_{i,2}$
associated to hyperplane
$H_{\lambda}^i$ is encoded as $i$-th row of a matrix $R \in Mat_{n+1}(K(\lambda))$
and we set zeroes in $n+1$ row, the $(n+1)$-th column of

Comment: adjungate matix
$A$ to $R$ provides for varying $\lambda$ the parametrization 
$[A_0(\lambda):...:A_n(\lambda)]$
of curve
$\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_t^1 \cap ... \cap H_t^n$ by construction.

Comment: But on linear independence of $A_i(\lambda)$ you are right, that's not clear
at all. My hope was that there is a pure geometric way playing only
on $\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_t^1 \cap ... \cap H_t^n$ and
analyse it's intersections with hyperplanes would give us a
contradiction if we assume that it is contained in a hyperplane,
but up to now I haven't found an argument for arbitrary but pairwise
distinct $\Lambda_1, ..., \Lambda_n$. In the construction itself
Harris not mentioned explicitely that one should impose 
nondegeneracy of

Comment: $\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_t^1 \cap ... \cap H_t^n$
as *additional* assumption, so I think this must somehow
follow from construction, but I don't know